# Interface Segregation Principle - Multiple Client Apps

Tags: interface-segregation-principle

I’m developing a shared library and using Interface Segregation.

There will be multiple client apps using this library and I was wondering about how to name each interface.

Some apps will share interfaces and some will use their own.
If App 1 uses Interface1, we could call Interface1 “IApp1” but if App2 also uses Interface1, it could become confusing.

If we then created a separate interface for App2, it would be descriptive, but then we’re duplicating code.

Then we will have App3 which uses a different set of methods, would we create “IApp3”?
Are there any best practices for this?

Thanks

I have named them with temporary names for testing

Comment: Especially when designing a library you cannot care about what apps use your library, you cannot know it upfront. And anyway that is not what ISP is about, it is about designing interfaces in a "sensible" way: don't force your Square class to have a getRadius method just because a Circle also extends the shared interface Geometry and you added the method there. What classes and Interfaxes do you actually have and how are they logically grouped? If a client decides not to call a method it sees that is something entirely different to that method being / not being there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 2 apps are .NET and 1 is a different environment and they use parameters differently. They both need to achieve the same result, but the parameters are different depending on the App type. I don't want to force .NET apps to use more complex parameter types that are required for other environments. Hope that makes sense.